# How to fetch content:encoded tags information from rss

Tags: php, rss, blogs

Am fetching blog from wordpress to my website using **magpierss-0.72** rss parser now i want to fetch image from my blog, the image in  tag like

```
<content:encoded><img src="path" /></content:encoded>
```

my code what i have tried is

```
require_once('rss_fetch.inc');
$rss = fetch_rss($url);

foreach ($rss->items as $i => $item ) {
$title = strtoupper ($item['title']);
$url = $item['link'];
$date = $item['pubdate'];
$desc = $item['description'];
$content = $item['content:encoded'];
echo $title."<br />";
echo $url."<br />";
echo $date."<br />";
echo $desc."<br />";
echo $content."<br />";
}
```

But the details in content:encode tag is not fetching. Can any one help me Please

Thank you in advance

Comment: i just gave it to count the number of blogs to stop the display of blogs after some number of blogs

Answer (score 0):

It should be parsed into the `$item['content']['encoded']` field if your feed is an Atom feed or under `$item['atom_content']` if your feed is an RSS feed.

For reference see the `rss_parse.php`, `MagpieRSS::parse` method.